# Getting files to imagelist1

Tags: vb.net

The code given below generates an error. Conversion from string "C:..." to integer not valid.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Application.ExecutablePath) & "Images"
    For Each fileName As String In path
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(fileName))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This line causes the error: Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\Images"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment.GetFolderPath Gets the path to the system special folder that is identified by the specified enumeration.

Application.ExecutablePath itself gives a path string. So use any one of them.

Comment: File not found. For Each fileName As String In path is this correct?

Comment: Check weather you need to provide file extension also.

Comment: I forgot to use Try Catch! I have to use Application.StartupPath and not Application.Executablepath. Thanks & best regards, Geek.

Comment: For Each fileName As String In path ' result shows the letter C and not the complete path & file name.

Comment: C must be a file at that path.

Comment: It is referring to the drive letter probably C. msgbox(path) gives me the correct location and the full path. But msgbox(filename) in the for next loop gives me a C. Pls let me know if should open a new post!

Comment: For Each fileName As String In path.... This is a wrong logic. it will check each string in path. u need to use Path.GetFileName(fileName). Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Comment: result = path.GetFileName(fileName) underlined in blue!